# bash variable created with awk moves in echo output

Tags: bash, variables, awk

my while loop is reading a file that looks like:

```
Chr start stop value  
chr1 12345 4345666 -1
```

to compare with another file to create mean values of those values (probes.txt):

```
chr1 12345 12345 0.124  
chr1 12346 12346 0.421
```

now the code goes:

```
$file | while read line
do 
first=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}' )
second=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
third=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
logsum=$(awk -v first=$first  -v second=$second -v third=$third '$1==first && $2>= second && $3<=third { sum += $4; n++} END { print sum / n; }' probes.txt
echo "$line" "$logsum"
done
```

the output that I am expecting would be:

```
chr1 12345 4345666 -1 0.232
```

but instead the $logsum ends up at the front overriding parts of the $line:

```
 0.232345 4345666 -1 0.232
```

i have also tried printf and get the same issue with

```
printf "%s %s \n" "$line" "$logsum"
```

i think the problem is the $logsum variable as it seems ok if I

```
echo "$logsum" "$line"
```

instead.

Does anyone know what is happening here and how to fix it?

**edit** I am working on a Mac in case this is an issue

**fixed** with dos2unix

Comment: Welcome to SO, not completely clear, could you please let us know which 2 numbers/fields  you need the mean?

Comment: Should the mean value to be `0.2725` in your example?

Comment: Could it be that your file `$file` has windows line-feeds in it (`\r\n` instead of just `\n`). Maybe `dos2unix` solves your problem.

Comment: You are calling the `awk` language interpreter four times for each loop iteration.  You could reduce this using:  `while read first second third theRest` (just glue them together for your final `echo`).

Comment: i just made up a random number for the mean here, as this loops over very large files. I checked the hidden characters with `cat -v` and only found an ^M which, when removed doesn't change anything

Comment: To emphasize @cdarke's comment, `while read line; do echo $line | (cut|awk)` is an anti-pattern.  Let `read` split the line into fields.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for SOME of the issues with your script. Also google "quoting shell variables" and "UUOC" for some of the others. You should strongly consider abandoning this and just writing a single awk script to do it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from checking for `\r\n` characters, as suggested by @kvantour, I'd recommend to do all of this in a single AWK script. This will be more efficient.

Let's say, if you save this to `script.awk`:

```
NR == 1 { print $0,"logsum"; next }
{
    sum = 0; n = 0; avg = 0;
    while(( getline line < fn) > 0) { 
            split(line, arr);
            if (arr[1]==$1 && arr[2]>=$2 && arr[3]<=$3) {
                    sum += arr[4]; n++;
            }
    }
    if (n>0) avg = (sum / n);
    print $0, avg;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
awk -v fn=probes.txt -f script.awk YOURFILE.txt
```

Example output:

```
Chr start stop value logsum
chr1 12345 4345666 -1 0.2725
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get this to work either. This is the file: 
`Chromosome Start  Stop Value 

chr1 109446507 109537862 -1  
chr1 158867881 159242170 -1  

chr9 3464597 3494038 -2  
chr10 30565643 30854992 -1  
chr12 12637644 14893621 1
chr20 31955124 31980522 -1  
chr20 32074006 32387166 1  `
and this is the output:

Comment: and this is the output:  logsumome Start  Stop Value;
 -0.4855229446507 109537862 -1;
 0r1 158867881 159242170 -1;
 0r9 3464597 3494038 -2;
 0r10 30565643 30854992 -1;
 0r12 12637644 14893621 1;
 0r20 31955124 31980522 -1;
 0r20 32074006 32387166 1;

the ";" here are just to show where the next line starts. I am a little overwhelmed by the commenting window (pressing enter too much). Hope this is comprehensible

Comment: @NinaHollfelder, run `dos2unix YOURFILE.txt`. This will convert newline characters in your file to UNIX format and all will work well. (No need to delete the ^M character manually.)

Comment: and this is what it should look like: -0.485522 chr1 109446507 109537862 -1;
-0.361409 chr1 158867881 159242170 -1;
-2.19458 chr9 3464597 3494038 -2;
-0.250712 chr10 30565643 30854992 -1;
0.145156 chr12 12637644 14893621 1;
-0.387729 chr20 31955124 31980522 -1;
0.365632 chr20 32074006 32387166 1;
except that column 1 here should be the fifth column

Comment: @NinaHollfelder, glad it helped. Also, if you find my answer useful, consider choosing it as "Best answer". (Though, dos2unix solution for `\r\n` was first suggested by @kvantour.)

Comment: Doing it all in awk is the right approach. Doing it with getline is almost certainly the wrong approach. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for a discussion of the issues.